# Can we force load .NET 4.7.2 with electron-edge-js? .Net 4.5.2 has security issue where TLS 1.0 is used

Tags: .net, electron

We've noticed that our Electron app appears to be loading .NET 4.5.2 which is causing our HTTPS connections to use TLS 1.0.

Our understanding from experimentation and reading this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

... is that .Net 4.7.2 and newer "do the right thing", meaning the connections are established using the newest protocol supported by the server, in our case, TLS 1.2 or 1.3.

We are using Electron 1.7.9 with Node 8.16.
electron-edge-js version is 12.0.1

Is there some sort of configuration that would allow us to force using .NET 4.7.2?

Thanks very much! Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you build your DLL with 4.7.2 ?, since electron-edge-js does not define any version at all.

Comment: @HansKoch yes, we build our dll in Visual Studio targeting .Net 4.7.2. Part of the problem here is that unlike with a classic.Net exe where you can use an app.config to specify the .Net ‘supportedRuntime’, with electron-edge-js it’s unclear how the .Net version gets picked by the system.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to accomplish your goal.

First is to add an `Electron.exe.config` to your directory that contains the `Electron.exe` (or the name your Electron app was renamed to).

Or, and that is just my favorite if you do not really need new APIs of 4.7.2, just add single-line of code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This enforces TLS 1.2 only. Don't use or leave the `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault` set, because most systems allow the older ones and the preferences of the .NET framework are not the best.

Comment: We tried to to add an <appname>.exe.config with the `supportedRuntime` element but it did not appear to work. Setting the `SecurityProtocol` works, though.